# How do I validate a form while the person is typing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tested out the new JQuery version I got from someone and now nothing works at all. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Again, I am using Bootstrap.

Javascript

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#first').keyup( function(){
    var x=document.forms["signup"]["first"].value;
    if(x.length<3 || x.length>16) {
        $('#errornote').html('<p class="bg-danger">You need to enter your first name.</p>')
    }
})

$('#email').keyup( function(){
    var x=document.forms["signup"]["email"].value;
    var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
      {
        $("#eemail").attr("class","alert alert-warning alert-dismissable flyover flyover-centered");
        $("#eemail").append("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, youre not looking too good.");
        return false;
      }
})
```

HTML

```
<form action="#" class="form" id="signup" role="form">   <legend>Sign Up</legend>
                    <h4>Its free and always will be.</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6" id="first">
                            <input type="text" id="first" name="firstname" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name"  /></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6" id="last">
                            <input type="text" id="last" name="lastname" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name"  /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="email"><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Your Email"  /></div>
                    <div id="eemail"></div>
```

Comment: Please add Your HTML code. There is not enough data to answer

Comment: @KrzysztofWende I added the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do my form validation with jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/j63PC/

I use `$("#check").on('input')` to check whenever a input field changes:

Comment: I tried to use your code and it does not even run. I don't know what's going on. The console does not show any errors.

Comment: @ChrisMP first, try entering in 1 or 2 characters, and also check that you have JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal/Sm28x/

Of course, this is an example as your code looks a little verbose for me to investigate into.
See if what I have gives you any insight on why your code isn't working. This example only allows numerals/numerics. Anything else will insert the error text above the input. Of course, I don't have error resetting and things like that. This is just a base example.

example html:

```
<div class="container">
  <form id="testform">
     <span id="errornote"></span>
         <input type="text" id="txttest">
</form>
</div>
```

in javascript: using jquery plugin

```
$('#txttest').keyup( function(){
    if( /\D+/.test( $(this).val() )) {
        $('#errornote').html('<font color="red">Non numeric added: Only numerics allowed</font>')
    }
})
```

Comment: I edited my original post and tried your code, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Wrtie your code with in $(document).ready(), like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#first').keyup( function(){
      var x=document.forms["signup"]["first"].value;
     if(x.length<3 || x.length>16) {
    $('#errornote').html('<p class="bg-danger">You need to enter your first name.</p>')
    }
  });

$('#email').keyup( function(){
var x=document.forms["signup"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
    $("#eemail").attr("class","alert alert-warning alert-dismissable flyover flyover-centered");
    $("#eemail").append("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, youre not looking too good.");
    return false;
      }
   });

 });
```